# Adding number to varchar and comparing the result with another varchar value

Tags: sql, oracle

There is Sq l-Report I am working on and I need some help from the experts on this forum.

The report is to find all the late comers and early going people in the place.
I have to add 10 minutes in the minute part of `varchar2` type column and the values inside this column are like '10:41', means I have to make it '10:51' after adding it with 10(number).
I have applied to_number but it doesn't work.

My Oracle version = 7.0

Query I am using is like:

```
select adm,emp_num,adm_emp_name,asm_st_tme,asm_ed_tme from adm,asm
where adm_emp_num =120342
having min(to_char(adm_ace_tme,'HH24:MI')) < asm_st_tme
group by adm,emp_num,adm_emp_name,asm_st_tme,asm_ed_tme
```

Structure of Adm table is :

```
ADM_ID              NUMBER(10,0)        Yes     1       
ADM_EMP_NUM         NUMBER(6,0) Yes     2       
ADM_EMP_NAM         VARCHAR2(35 BYTE)   Yes     3       
ADM_CRD_NUM         VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)   Yes     4       
ADM_ACE_DTE         DATE                Yes     5       
ADM_ACE_TME         DATE                Yes     6       
ADM_DOR_NUM         NUMBER(4,0) Yes     7       
ADM_DOR_NAM        VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)    Yes     8       
ADM_DOR_STE        VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)    Yes     9       
ADM_IN_OUT         VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)     Yes     10      
ADM_MAC_TYP        VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)    Yes     11
```

Structure of Asm Table is:

```
ASM_ID      NUMBER(1,0)
ASM_SFT     VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
ASM_ST_TME  VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)
ASM_ED_TME  VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)
```

Comment: Version 7? As in, 1992 version 7? And can you show a little more of your code?

Comment: Yes, the 1992 version.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must use this cols as timestamp rather than varchar. Use alter command to do this. And then you can use following syantax to get desired result.

```
SELECT SYADATE, SYADATE + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I CANNOT MODIFY THE STRUCTURE.